# fortran memory allocation error ::Operating system error: Cannot allocate memory

Tags: memory, fortran, gfortran

I am writing a 4d matrix of size (1000,1000,5000,6) which the variable allocated but it is showing

**Operating system error: Cannot allocate memory
Allocation would exceed memory limit**
*with error traceback to*

```
#0  0x402487 in MAIN__
        at /temp.f90:67
#1  0x400c1c in main
        at /temp.f90:158
```

where

> integer, parameter :: n=10000

> > temp.f90:67 :: allocate(xi(n))
> > temp.f90:158 :: end program

Comment: Welcom, please take the [tour]. I also suggest to read [ask]. For a default real the array will take 112 GM of memory. For double precision 224 GB of memory. Do you have that much memory? We probably have some similar earlier question as a duplicate. Please always show more code, not just tue line from the error message.

Comment: To be clear, the 1000x1000x5000x6 would take that much memory.  A `xi(10000)` array is small. To be completely clear please do show the whole code. See [mcve].

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.